# When was a file last opened?

Tags: ls, timestamps, coreutils

How do I determine, when a file was last opened?

I've looked at `man ls` (using GNU coreutils 8.22) and I don't see anything about this timestamp.

Comment: In general it's called "access time" or atime.  Note that it can be disabled for `ext` filesystems, meaning it will not be updated for files as long as the fs is so mounted.

Comment: @goldilocks, _access time_ is the time the file was last _read_, not _open_. Opening a file (as in the `open()` system call) doesn't update any time stamp unless it's an open with truncation (`O_TRUNC`).

Answer (score 12):

You may want to check this:

```
ls -l --time=atime

atime — updated when file is read
mtime — updated when the file changes.
ctime — updated when the file or owner or permissions changes.
```

Have fun! :)

Comment: (note that none of them is for the time the file was last open which is not an information that is recorded. Also, for performance reason,  `atime` is rarely always updated nowadays)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
ls -lu
```

If you want sorted result by access time:

```
ls -ltu
```

From `man ls`:

```
-u     with  -lt:  sort  by, and show, access time with -l: show access
              time and sort by name otherwise: sort by access time
```

If you want to get full date time, use `--full-time`:

```
$ ls -ltu --full-time
```

Or use `GNU stat`:

```
$ stat -c "%x" -- test.txt 
2014-06-30 19:21:05.481161360 +0700
```

Comment: I am only getting month and day of access time, is there a way to get the year? I tried using `date` like args, but that didn't work.

Comment: @TobiLehman: See updated answer.

Comment: @TobiLehman According to http://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/ls-info.html: "However, the **default POSIX locale uses a date like Mar 30 2002 for non-recent timestamps, and a date-without-year and time like Mar 30 23:45 for recent timestamps. A timestamp is considered to be "recent" if it is less than six months old, and is not dated in the future.** If a timestamp dated today is not listed in recent form, the timestamp is in the future, which means you probably have clock skew problems which may break programs like make that rely on file timestamps." --Emphasis mine

Comment: With GNU `ls`, use `--full-time` to get the full time (with as much precision as available).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use GNU `stat` command. Example: `stat my_file.txt` will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: `linux` has not `stat` command, Linux is just a kernel. There are several `stat` commands found on Linux and non-Linux based systems like GNU stat, zsh stat...